# how to install libbow?

Tags: 10.10, libraries

Does any one installed [libbow](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mccallum/bow/) on ubuntu 10.10?
Seems the code is not upgraded for latest compiler. when i try to follow the instruction to install the same, i got error during compilation stage.

It was included in the source package for [hardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/libbow). They removed it later.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, until two days ago! :)

I went to http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/libbow/download and then I downloaded a .deb package. Then you just double click on it or if you prefer you can install it through the terminal and that's it. With this, you don't have to compile anything.

I hope it can work on you.

Regards.